# CLLocationManager/MKMapView with external GPS

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview, external, cllocationmanager

I've had reports from multiple users saying that their external GPS units (Bad Elf, mostly) aren't working with my GPS-enabled app. I'm not doing any manually detection for GPS units; the app assumes the device has a unit and just displays an error if no location is found. My question is:

Is there any additional setup that needs to be done to allow a CLLocationManager and MKMapView to interact with an external GPS on a device with no internal GPS unit?

Comment: Sounds like the same problem other app developers had with iOS6 and external GPS devices. Google for them and you will get to articles like http://blog.foreflight.com/2012/10/02/external-gps-devices-and-ios-6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Till pointed out in his comment, it seems that this is a problem with iOS 6. You can read more about it [here](http://www.hiltonsoftware.com/iOS6-GPSIssue.html) as well as in the link that he provided.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do anything about this. This is an issue for Apple and the GPS vendor. You are using an API to access the internal GPS.